# Pegar nome através do ID do usuário

Tags: php, sql

Tenho que pegar o id do meu usuário e salvar em uma variável o nome referente a esse id, porém não esta dando certo !

```
    function inReg() {

    global $connect;

    $id_usuario = $_POST["id_usuario"];
    $denuncia = $_POST["denuncia"];

    $nome = "SELECT nome FROM usuario WHERE id_usuario = '$id_usuario'";

    $query = " Insert into denuncia (id_usuario, denuncia) values 
   ('$id_usuario','$denuncia')";
    mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    mysqli_close($connect);



    require 'rotinas_emails/registro_denuncia_mail.php';

 }

 ?>
```

Nesta variável $nome está salvando o próprio sql "  Nova Denuncia enviada por SELECT nome FROM usuario WHERE id_usuario = '74'"

Comment: Precisa executar o select no seu código vc só criou um string com um comando sql.

Comment: os id_usuario das duas tabelas são iguais? para que o select nome da tabela usuario?

Comment: Na verdade e somente uma tabela, esse select eu faço para poder enviar a variável nome para outra pagina que será realizado o envio de um email com os dados.

Answer (score 4):

Você tem que executar o query e ler o valor retornado, para fazer isso, dessa maneira:

```
$select = "SELECT nome FROM usuario WHERE id_usuario = '$id_usuario'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($connect, $select);
row = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);
$nome = row[0];
```

Comment: Ok, havia tentado de maneiras semelhantes, mas quando coloco esse codigo ele nem salva mais em meu banco, como se ele parasse de executar nestas linhas .

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta). Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Comment: hahaha, muitos vem aqui pegam a solução e desaparecem sem ao menos marcar como aceita, um up pra compensar  o trabalho

Answer (score 2):

Lembre, uma query não se auto executa e pega as informações do banco. Para isso você precisa usar o mysqli_fetch_array.

O mysqli_fetch_array irá retornar uma linha correspondente a sua query ao banco.

Então você cria sua query, executa no mysqli_query, e pega a linha com o fetch_array. Após isso você terá como acessar o índice desse resultado. Por exemplo.

```
$nome = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

echo $nome['a_coluna_que_deseja_saber_do_banco'];
```

Depois que fez tudo isso , é só jogar o resultado em uma query e ta lá.

Não sou muito familiarizado com mysqli... mas é basicamente isso.

Comment: Não entendi a parte de jogar em um query

Comment: Por exemplo essa linha que postei voce pegou uma quantidade de denuncias.. $nome['qtdDenuncias'] . Ai com base nisso voce precisa criar outra query ... $queryProcura = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '1' AND qtdDenunciasUser = {'$nome[qtdDenuncias]'}; .... So um exemplo ,nao faz sentido mas um exemplo que voce pode pegar o resultado de uma linha do banco de uma query sua e colocar em outra query para outra pesquisa. Mals se deixei complicado, tentei deixar facil.